# How to fetch the event page from Facebook, NOT just the data

Tags: facebook

Is there way to display Facebook event page in my website, it should contain all the functionality as there in Facebook.

Using graph API and SDK I can get the content, but I want all the buttons (attend, maybe, etc)
with Facebook design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Facebook's content but you can't try to make a mirror of the page, which is proprietary.

Use an inline frame (iframe) to *display* (not copy) the page you want in your own website.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: But facebook will not display content in iframe

Comment: There it is saying to fetch content using AJAX, But i guess it will show cross domain error, So you can not fetch contents from other domain using AJAX.

Comment: What i actually need is to display the event page of facebook in my website, I could not find any way, Please help me if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly do a  curl request for the page and just output the retrieved call into your site?